# Chrome flagged superuser.com as "dangerous"

Tags: support, status-review

I don't know if this is from some global blacklist or if it's unique to my machine, but Chrome just popped up this annoying warning when attempting to visit superuser.com:

[image]

Not sure if it matters to anybody, just reporting it in case there's some process somebody needs to go through to get it unblacklisted (assuming it's not just me).

Not sure why I got this.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce it on my machine with a fresh chrome install

Comment: I can't reproduce firsthand either, but https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=https:%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2F&hl=en seems to indicate a problem of some sort ("Some pages on this site are unsafe").

Comment: Working perfectly normally for me, but I do get that warning occasionally for all sorts of random sites including, once, Google itself.

Comment: It's probably because sometimes people share links to various utility tools in answers, maybe some of them are in that "can be used by hackers" category. Password recovery, system tweaks, etc. That's my theory anyways.

Comment: Such an annoying Chrome feature.